# How to add BNode to binary search tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

From our assignment, a question want's us to write a method in the BTree class. It has to take an integer as a parameter, and then adds it to the tree. So I did that:

```
public void add(int v){
    if(root == null){
        root = new BNode(v);
    }
    else{
        add(v, root);
    }
}
public void add(int v, BNode branch){
    if(v == branch.getVal()){
        return;
    }
    if(v<branch.getVal()){
        if(branch.getLeft() == null){
            branch.setLeft(new BNode(v));
        }
        else{
            add(v, branch.getLeft());
        }
    }
    else{
        if(branch.getRight() == null){
            branch.setRight(new BNode(v));
        }
        else{
            add(v, branch.getRight());
        }
    }
}
```

But i wonder how do you add when the parameter of the method is just a BNode? Is it just:

```
public void add(BNode b){
    add(BNode.getVal());
}
```

Is there no more efficient way of doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, turn your paramter types the other way: make your methods to not expect an `int` but a `BNode`. So change this:

```
public void add(int v, BNode branch)
```

to

```
public void add(BNode v, BNode branch)
```

and change:

```
public void add(int v)
```

to

```
public void add(BNode v)
```

and then create a different method:

```
public void add(int b){
    add(new BNode(b));
}
```

This way you're avoiding to create one extra object in memory.